# phpmyadmin issuing a fatal error for PMA_DBI_num_rows()

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, apache2

Doing a simple phpmyadmin install on a new server and I get the white screen.

Going into the apache logs I see:

```
[Wed Jun 19 23:20:57 2013] [error] [client 67.154.118.163] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function PMA_DBI_num_rows() in /var/www/phpmyadmin/libraries/navigation/Nodes/Node.class.php on line 408
```

All I have done on the server is install apache, php, mysql, and the php-mysql module...

No idea whats going on :(

Comment: Which version of phpMyAdmin are you installing?

Comment: it was the new one 4.08 or whatever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check your `php5-mysql` php module if it is installed correctly
(maybe you forgot apache restart?)

had the same issue and after checking php-mysql module again and fixing it, this error vanished

Comment: I'm going to mark this correct, but I eventually just used the Ubuntu package and it fixed whatever the issue was

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

This will remove php5-mysql but it worked for me.