# phpmyadmin is white page

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I installed on my win 7 apache 2.4, PHP 5.5.3, mysql 5.6  & last version of phpmymyadmin

I checked my server and it's working good as the phpinfo(); is working correctly.

When I installed phpmyadmin I got a blank white page without any errors, so I checked the apache error log and received below error

```
[Tue Sep 10 20:40:48.431821 2013] [:error] [pid 2344:tid 1048] [client ::1:59511] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function PMA_DBI_num_rows() in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\phpMyAdmin\\libraries\\navigation\\Nodes\\Node.class.php on line 397
```

Any idea what's wrong and how to solve?

Comment: Did you try this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203336/phpmyadmin-issuing-a-fatal-error-for-pma-dbi-num-rows

Comment: Is your MySQL server working?

Comment: @JohannesN, He says it is on windows 7.

Comment: Hi Starx, how I can check if mysql server is working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You miss the mysql or mysqli PHP extension (or they are not active). See
https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3997/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use xampp or wampp ? http://apachefriends.org